# Red words only in css (SASS syntax) files with vim editor

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I try to remove the highlighted words with `:set nospell` command and I can't.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

I'm working with vim 7.4 on Archlinux with gnome-shell desktop.

Thanks! Any suggestion is accepted :)

Comment: Well, that's not CSS so… do you use a SASS syntax script?

Comment: Oh sorry! you right! I use SASS syntax, but I have any plugin for this